# How can I select a row having a BigInt and a DateTime field starting with a specigic value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I am working on a Microsoft SQL Server database and I have the following problem to implement these 2 simple select query.

So I have a table named `MyTable` that has a column `OtherFieldFK` of type `BigInt` with a value of `70016592107`.

So for example I want search all the record in this table that have the `OtherFieldFK` starting with the value `70`.

I tried to use `like` in this way:

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where OtherFieldFK like = '70%'
```

but it doesn't work. I think that like clause works only on string, is it right?

In this table I also have a `DATETIME` column named `DataInizioGestione`.

I tried to do the same thing:

```
select * 
from DataInizioGestione
where OtherFieldFK like = '2016%'
```

but in this case it doesn't work either.

How can I correctly implement these 2 queries?

Comment: How about changing your query to **select * from MyTable where OtherFieldFK like '70%'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first should be right, as you wrote:

```
select * from MyTable where OtherFieldFK like = '70%'
```

for the second should be converted to the date format in the nvarchar (es 121 with this format aaaa-mm-gg hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)); in this way you can make the comparison with the like:

```
select * from MyTable where convert(nvarchar,DataInizioGestione,121) like = '2016%'
```

or you can directly compare the year:

```
select * from MyTable where year(DataInizioGestione) = 2016
```